# load an image into this image box from an embedded image

Tags: excel, image

Is there ANY WAY to load an image into this image box from an object that I have loaded into an excel worksheet something like

```
    if userform1.checkbox1=True Then 
    userform1.image.picture = loadpicture (Worksheets("Sheet1").shapes("Picture 1")) endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Locate the image that you want to use, and copy it to the Clipboard.

Activate the VB Editor and select the object that will contain the image (i.e., a

UserForm, or a control that has a Picture property).

Make sure the Properties window is displayed (press F4 it it's not).

Click the Picture item. By default, this displays "(None)" as in the figure above.

Press Ctrl+V to paste the image on the Clipboard to the control.